# css inset not rendering in Safari

Tags: css

Why Safari does not accept `inset`?

I have a code with the inset property in React

```
<div style={{position: 'absolute', inset: '0px 0px 0px 0px'}}>
```

When I check the Safari element, it is not there and if I try to manually add, it does not allow me. Works just fine with Firefox and Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Because it's [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset#browser_compatibility) in Safari.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset#browser_compatibility - Doesn't seem compatible with Safari

Comment: Thanks. I think the solution is setting all the positions: top, bottom, right, and left